# Reading/filtering excel color font cell

Tags: java, excel, filtering, talend

I need to filter out excel colored text lines, I found that tFilterRow is not able to do it, is someone were able to resolve that using Java code or some other way?

BR,
Val

Comment: Sorry I don't think it is possible with talend.

Comment: This needs a lot more detail. Do you want to filter using Excel VBA, another programing language that is reading the Excel file?